# Implementing wild card searches on a django model

Tags: python, django

I have a model called Host where I store all the information about all my servers. In the model I have a field `hostname`.

I would like for the user to be able to specify wildcard searches like: `*one` where they'd get all the hosts with hostnames ending in `one` or
`one*` where they'd get all the hosts with hostnames starting with `one`
and `one*two` and `*one*two` and `*one*two*` and `*one*two*three` and `one*two*three` and so forth.

I have tried iterating over the results of `hostname.split('*')` but I end up with confusing if/elif continue mess.  Does anyone know a more elegant way to handle wildcards?

Comment: Try using `Q` objects with your `split` method and join them using the `|` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html) ?

```
import fnmatch

print(fnmatch.fnmatch('foo.info', 'foo*'))
print(fnmatch.fnmatch('foo.info', '*.info'))
print(fnmatch.fnmatch('nope', '*.info'))
```

Gives

```
True
True
False
```

You still have to iterate, but have to handle a single one `if`.